# Expressjs and TypeScript - unable to type express

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am trying to properly type nodejs application with use of express and TypeScript. Consider this code:

```
import express, { Router } from "express";
import { DeviceController } from "../controller/device.controller";

export class DeviceRouter {
  public router: Router;

  private deviceController: DeviceController;

  constructor() {
    this.deviceController = new DeviceController();
    this.router = express.Router();

    this.router.get("/", this.deviceController.index);
    this.router.post("/", this.deviceController.create);
    this.router.delete("/:id", this.deviceController.delete);
  }
}
```

This leads to error

```
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/module/device/router/device.router.ts:13:17 - error TS2339: Property 'get' does not exist on type 'Router'.

13     this.router.get("/", this.deviceController.index);
                   ~~~
src/module/device/router/device.router.ts:14:17 - error TS2339: Property 'post' does not exist on type 'Router'.

14     this.router.post("/", this.deviceController.create);
                   ~~~~
src/module/device/router/device.router.ts:15:17 - error TS2339: Property 'delete' does not exist on type 'Router'.

15     this.router.delete("/:id", this.deviceController.delete);
               ~~~~~~
```

Of course when router is typed as `any` everything is working as intended. I have the same problem with typing `app`, firstly code example when everything is working good:

```
import express from "express";

class App {
  public app: any;

  constructor() {
    this.app = express();
  }
}

export default new App().app;
```

and example when typing leads to error:

```
import express, { Application } from "express";

class App {
  public app: Application;

  constructor() {
    this.app = express();
  }
}

export default new App().app;
```

result:

```
src/server.ts:5:5 - error TS2339: Property 'listen' does not exist on type 'Application'.

5 app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}!`));
```

My configuration:

macOS Catalina 10.15.2
node.js v10.16.0

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

relevant dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "~4.17.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "~4.17.2",
    "@types/node": "~13.5.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.6.2",
    "typescript": "~3.7.5"
  }
```

Comment: How to run your server? `ts-node ..your.ts` right? Because I've been try your code and it's working fine.

Comment: I am running it through nodemon, but I tried to run it directly via ts-node and the same error pops out. Moreover, I tried it now on arch linux and it is exactly the same, so it is not platform dependent.

Comment: Interesting. I am using rushjs as a monorepo manager and pnpm as package manager. When I use npm everything is working as expected. So I think that it is not connected with typescript and express types but rush or pnpm itself.